# Create a slideshow video with the date added as a text automatically

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing, slideshow, exif

Is there a way to Create a slideshow with the date as a caption automatically?

So basically, I want to create a slideshow video of family photos and as each image is displayed the date and time of the image are displayed as a caption at the bottom.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I know this can be done in Premiere Pro manually but that will take forever as there are thousands of photos.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? There are bunch of various googlable solutions, did you attempt any? Also, please don't tag software you're specifically listing as something you don't want to use. Tags should describe what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easily done in a third-party tool that can display EXIF and IPTC data, such as free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/), or perhaps an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/irfanview/). In IrfanView:

- Press <kbd>W</kbd> to enter *Slideshow* mode.
- Select images to display.
- In the *Show text* box, add `$E36867` to [display the date/time](https://irfanview-forum.de/forum/program/support/95475-for-a-slideshow-t-doesn-t-display-date-taken-it-displays-date-modified-instead) from EXIF data.

[image: IrfanView Slideshow]

The slideshow can be saved as a screen saver (SCR), executable, or video, as well as stored for playing within IrfanView.

Of course, other EXIF and IPTC data can be shown too, such as the camera model and geographic location, if recorded, to help bring back memories elicited by the photo.